# Callback function doesn't work in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, callback

I'm writting web client for my Exchange Server and I have problem. One of the functions responsible for the getting a current state of user wallet. But after receive answer from server the callback function doesn't work (only in firefox). In Chrome, Opera and Safari it's working good without problem. I'm sure than the problem is on the client side becouse server send completely data.

Code of my function :

```
proto.on("login", function(status, settings) {
    user.waluta = user.currency(settings.waluta);
    user.session = settings.idSesja;
    proto.getWallet(settings.idSesja, settings.waluta, function(result){
        setUserWallet(result);
    });
    window.location.reload();

});
```

And code of "getWallet" :

```
self.getWallet = function(sesja, waluta, callback, successCallback, failureCallback) {
        if (self.isConnected()) {
            var ses = {
                '@class': 'event.IDSesji',
                'idSesji': sesja,
                'login': self.username
            };
            self.socket.json.emit('dajPortfel', {
                '@class': 'event.DajPortfel',
                'waluta': waluta,
                'sesja': ses
            }, function(data) {
                if (data.kod == ResultStatus.ok) {
                    callback(data.zalacznik);
                    if (isFunc(successCallback)) successCallback(data.zalacznik);
                } else {
                    if (isFunc(failureCallback)) failureCallback(data.kod);
                }
            });
        } else {
            if (isFunc(jobDoneHandler)) { jobDoneHandler(ResultStatus.notConnected); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The call to `window.location.reload()` probably just aborts the page before that asynchronous operation completes. That call should probably be done inside the "getWallet" callback.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, that was the reason. When I delete `window.location.reload()` it's working fine.